Are put actions in redux-sagas dealt with atomically together with the triggering action?
Suppose I have a redux state with two slices. Each slice holds one number.
One number is controlled with the action SET_NUMBER and the other number is controlled with SET_OTHER_NUMBER.
Furthermore I have a saga that tries to make sure that the other number always matches the first. Something like this:
function* changeOtherNumber(action) {
    yield put(setOtherNumber(action.payload.number))
}

function* watchSetNumber() {
  yield takeEvery('SET_NUMBER', changeOtherNumber)
}

My question: If I dispatch a SET_NUMBER action, will I ever run the risk of (even momentarily) render a component where the numbers do not equal each other? Or will the saga kick in and change the the other number before any rerender has the chance to run? Put differently, is SET_OTHER_NUMBER dispatched and processed atomically together with SET_NUMBER from the react applications perspective?

The docs says the following:

put(action)​
Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to schedule the dispatching of an action to the store. This dispatch may not be immediate since other tasks might lie ahead in the saga task queue or still be in progress.
You can, however, expect the store to be updated in the current stack frame (i.e. by the next line of code after yield put(action)) unless you have other Redux middlewares with asynchronous flows that delay the propagation of the action.

but I have a hard time wrapping my head around those formulations.

If the put action is not run atomically / synchronously with the original SET_COLOR action what would the recommended approach be to do atomic updates like these? Or should I rethink the design completely?

For synchronous actions, you can use just reducers, they will guarantee that everything will be applied at the same moment. Every saga runs asynchronously, so it will be possible that with performance problems and slow renders, you can notice a difference, but the possibility is pretty low
another option is to send the initial action to Saga but not change anything in the data and then you can change both numbers synchronously at the action from Saga
